# How to access the current instance in nuxt page validate()?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I return a `Promise` in `validate()`. Now, I want to pass the data which is returned in the validation by the server to one of the methods. However, I am not able to do this. Please help!

```
    validate({ params, store, context }) {
        return store.dispatch(types.VALIDATE_PARAMS_ASYNC, params.id).then(data => {
            this.saveSettings(this, data)
            return true
        }).catch(e => {
            return false
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. Validate executed before the instance initialized, so you cant access methods. And validate isnt supposed to be used that way.

For passing data to need either to save them into vuex store ( preferably in [fetch](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch) method ) or return them as data in [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/api/) method. Then you can do what you want with your data in for example mounted method, or beforeMounted.